# Specify the base of the log function

Tags: r

I am bit confuse with R log function:
log(10) = 1 in base 10
but when I type this in R log(10) = 2.302585
So my question is how do I implicitly tell the base in R log function.

Comment: This is explicitly stated in the documentation.  Please read `?log`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Arguments
>
> x  a numeric or complex vector. base   a positive or complex number:
>   the base with respect to which logarithms are computed. Defaults to
>   e=exp(1).

So you call function `log` with the second parameter 10 (base that you want).

For example:

```
> log(10,10)
[1] 1
```

Comment: there is also, as stated clearly in the documentation, the convenience function `log10`